# How to determine bounds of polar graph without graphing?

Tags: calculus, area, polar-coordinates, curves

Question: Find the area in the second quadrant bounded by $r = \cos θ + \sin θ.$

[answer with picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJ19B.png)

Answer: The radial lines that bound the portion in the second quadrant are $θ = π/2$ (which makes sense) and $θ = 3π/4$. The second value makes $r = θ$ (since the sine and cosine of $3π/4$ are opposites), which is the intersection at the pole marking the end of the region’s presence in the second quadrant.

I was able to determine that $r=0$ in the second quadrant at $θ=3π/4$, but how do I know if the other bound is $π$ or $π/2$?

Comment: The "Answer:..." is copied and the "...(which makes sense)..." was written by the original author - it does not make sense to me! I just don't understand how they chose between the other bound being π/2 or π.

Answer (score 1):

By tabulating without graphing we have corresponding polar coordinates

$$\theta  (0, \pi/4,\pi/2, 3 \pi/4, \pi, 5 \pi/4, 3 \pi/2, 7 \pi/4 ) \;\&\; r (1, \sqrt 2, 1, 0,-1, -\sqrt 2, -1,0 ) $$

which gives the full calculated picture It is noted that in the second quadrant radius vector can be *positive, negative or zero*.

In this quadrant the total area is in fact zero.

The graphing ( rough sketch shown ) should be absent fully or be present in full, but not one half of it included up to  the middle of domain.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Curve is $r = \cos θ + \sin θ$. In polar coordinates, $x = r \cos \theta, y = r \sin \theta$.

Note that in second quadrant, $x \leq 0, y \geq 0$.

For $\frac{\pi}{2} \leq \theta \leq \frac{3\pi}{4}, |\sin\theta| \geq |\cos\theta|$, $\cos\theta$ is negative and $\sin\theta$ is positive.

So, $r \geq 0, x ( = r \cos\theta) \leq 0, y ( = r \sin\theta) \geq 0 $ and it is clear that the curve is in second quadrant.

For $\frac{3\pi}{4} \leq \theta \leq \pi, |\sin\theta| \leq |\cos\theta|$, again  $\cos\theta$ is negative and $\sin\theta$ is positive.

So, $r \leq 0, x ( = r \cos\theta) \geq 0, y ( = r \sin\theta) \leq 0 $ and it is clear that the curve is in fourth quadrant.

Does that explain why $\frac{\pi}{2} \leq \theta \leq \frac{3\pi}{4}$ in second quadrant?